# Select multipile column through Room liberary

Tags: android

I want to select multiple column from SqLite through Room Library in Android SDK environment. 
  Below is the query for selecting it.
   @Query("SELECT ID,message,timestamp FROM Chat_Message WHERE groupID =:groupID 
   ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1")
   public List get_last_msg_ID_timestamp (String 
    groupID);
    My Last_Msg_Detail class which is define under main class is as follows:-
      public class Last_Msg_Detail {
        public Integer ID;
        public String message;
        public Long timestamp;
       }

```
   For accessing this three variable have created below method :-
   Last_Msg_Detail last_record_t = new Last_Msg_Detail();
   public Last_Msg_Detail get_last_msgand_time_stamp(String groupID){
    List<Last_Msg_Detail> last_record = 
    chat_messageDao.get_last_msg_ID_timestamp(groupID);
    last_record_t = last_record.get(0);
    return last_record_t;
   } 
On Rebuilding Project, getting follow error 
 1. error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can 
 consider adding a type converter for it.
 2. error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type

Kindly advise how to resolve.
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

your method return custom object and the object has a lot of fields.

so, when you try to return specific columns, you try to return a new object. so the error occurs.

to solve the problem, create a new object for the selected columns. it has to has these fields.

```
 ID,message,timestamp
```

and use the object in your method

```
@Query("SELECT ID,message,timestamp FROM Chat_Message WHERE groupID =:groupID ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1")
 public List<NEW_OBJECT> get_last_msg_ID_timestamp (String groupID);
```

Comment: Thanx @ Momen for suggestion. Will check and get back. Meanwhile request you to advise if we can able to select three columns instead of going through object way? Cant we have simpler way of retrieving the value? Thnx

Comment: sorry I think there is no way, maybe you can use      @TypeConverter see this
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data

or maybe you can select *  and return list<your_main_object> and then create getter and setter. so you can use just (getId, getMessage, getTimestamp) methods